# Does the inclusion of z-index increase browser processing times?

Tags: css, performance, z-index

I am developing a thoroughly CSS-based website which necessitates the usage of `z-index` several times, ranging in value from `-10000` to the upwards of `50000`.

Does the usage of `z-index`measurably increase the amount of time a supported browser takes the render the webpage? Is `z-index` considered a good practice or are there other alternatives which are either (1) faster to render and/or (2) more generally acceptable?

Comment: I have seen Google Maps API v2 use a z-index of 288,000,000 for markers near the south pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z-index are relative, not absolute. An element with z-index 1,000,000 renders in front of elements with lower z-index and behind elements with higher z-index. If does not mean that the browser will create 1,000,000 layers.

I think it is the number of distinct z-indexes ([stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) to be more precise) that matters.

Comment: +1; borrowing from an ex-coworker of mine: "The absolute value of z-index is in inverse proportion to how much the CSS writer understands their use".

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to make sure the elements are in the correct order in your document. Anything lower in the document will be rendered in front of anything higher in the document. It might not be the easiest thing to implement server side, but certainly this complies with your requirements:

1) faster to render
Most likely as this is the default DOM rendering mechanism.
2) more generally acceptable
Certainly.